# cakePHP Paginator related tables

Tags: cakephp, paginator

Novice question about the Paginator.
I have a DB with tables; country, regions and properties [and a few more tables]
Now when I do a view for the regions to displays the properties sorted by region: for example domain.com/regions/view/33 the Paginator counts and displays information related to the regions [a total of 60 regions] and I would like to have the Paginator to show/count for the amount of properties [3 properties] in region 33, How to get this done?

Here is my code in the RegionsController.php

```
public function index() {
    $this->Region->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array('limit' => 10,'order' => 'Region.id ASC');
    $this->set('regions', $this->paginate());
}

public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Region->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid region'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Region.' .$this->Region->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('region', $this->Region->find('first', $options));
    $this->paginate = array('limit' => 10,'order' => 'Region.id ASC');
    $this->set('regions', $this->paginate());
}
```

This is the code to display the Paginator in my view.ctp

```
<br />
<div class="regions view">
<b><center><?php echo nl2br(h($region['Region']['titletag'])); ?></center></b>
<div class="paging">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
?>
</div>
```

This is the code in the Region.php Model.

```
class Region extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
*
* @var string
*/
public $displayField = 'regionname';


/**
* belongsTo associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

/**
* hasMany associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $hasMany = array(
    'Property' => array(
        'className' => 'Property',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CakePHP's counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto) to retain a constant count of the number of properties per region.  It's crazy-easy, and CakePHP does all the work of keeping track for you.

Then, you'll just have a "property_count" field in your `regions` table, and voila - you can sort by it, filter by it...etc etc etc.

Every time you add a property or delete a property, CakePHP will update the count for you automatically.

Comment: Hi Dave, just being a novice, will try it, but how does the regions view property_count know I am watching a different region and there for the counter is changed, or is that going automatic?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Region::$belongsTo in /app/Model/Region.php on line 39

Comment: @Nick - this is not the place for people to help debug your code.  That's a simple error, and even specifies what the problem is.  If you don't understand it, a quick Google search will give you the answer.

Comment: As said I am a novice and eager to learn, ok... I solved the error because I had put the countercache in the wrong model, I had to put it in the Property model, but it is not working, looking in the DB all counts are 0 and i assume that is because this will only work if you actually add or delete a record. which is indeed confirmed reading the link you gave: "From now on, every time you add or remove a ImageComment associated to Image, the number within image_comment_count is adjusted automatically".

Comment: I changed the property_count in the regions table with phpmyadmin to the amount of properties but still no effect on the Paginator.

Comment: Now that you know that counter_cache is the answer, feel free to ask another question(s) about your problems implementing.

Comment: Dave, i created a counter, how can i assign this to the paginator, because I still have problems to get the paginator to work for the second model level?

Comment: @Nick - the counter should have a row in the main table now - which is how you'd display it in the pagination data.

Comment: This is not going to work it seems, now I have the Paginator displaying all correct information like pages, amount of properties, and so on. But in the view it displays ALL properties in one huge list instead of limit by 10 and the virtualfield to sort on a field in the second model doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it sounds like it would benefit from a new question that's worded as detailed as you can.

Comment: Dave, I have put up the new question.